Will these metal spikes hold up a 6 ft high wood fence
I’m building a large spanned fence. Will these metal stakes hold it up? 1 span will be about 100 ft.

Which metal spikes? Manufacturer and model number, please. Also, you should have intermediate posts in the 100 foot span of fence. How many posts do you plan to use?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the fence is a cable, then check out catenary curve.

No. I don't even need to see the product to say that. No drive-in anchor is even intended to hold up a fence. They're intended to hold position at the base, and not to keep a post from tipping over. (Or if they are, they don't do a great job.)
That fact that you're talking about extremely long spans (almost an industrial-level distance) only enhances this sentiment.
See also:

Replacing fence posts: embed in concrete or use mounting brackets?
Can I use 4x4 post bases to install a 6’ fence across the top of a wood deck?

